# method to subtract from an integer member variable not working as expected

Tags: java, if-statement, member

In my class I have set the member variable honey as follows:

```
int honey = 10;
```

What I want the following method to do is take as a parameter the amount of hooney required and either return that amount if it is available and remove the specified amount from the stores or return 0 if there is no honey to be had. My method is as follows:

```
public int takeHoney(int h2){
    if(h2 <= honey){
        honey = honey - h2;
        return h2;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When my test harness does this:

```
h.takeHoney(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

it does not go down the if branch as I wanted it to but down the else branch. Why is this?
Surely as it is using Integer.MAX_VALUE it is removing the exact value that is in the hive and therefore h2<= honey as it equals honey?

Comment: Who is Honey and who is h ? Also your method is returning a value not setting in anywhere.

Comment: Agree with @JorgeCampos. Do you store value of this function anywhere?  What is the value of Honey?

Comment: Because MAX_VALUE is larger than any `Honey` value you're apt to have.

Comment: @HotLicks I would say, at least equal not larger. If the Honey is an integer an has the value of MAX_VALUE it would attend the if. But you are rigth. Most likely the Honey value is less than MAX_VALUE.

Comment: BTW, standard Java coding convention is that symbols with Leading Caps are reserved for class names, and variables and methods start with a lower case letter.

Comment: changed my code to make honey lowercase to match convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "Honey" a global variable?
if yes what is its value?

"If" block will only work if value of variable Honey is greater than or equal to variable h2.
I think value of Honey is lesser than h2. So that is why else block is executed.

[EDIT]
You updated the question and clearly mention honey=10.

condition in if block  (h2 <= honey)

value of honey=10;

h2= Integer.MAX_VALUE= 2147483647 .
Clearly h2>honey .

So your if block will never be executed in this scenario.

change method call as follows

```
h.takeHoney(10);
```

or

```
h.takeHoney(9);
```

(your if block will be executed for any value lesser than 11)

Answer (score 0):

Honey is not equal to anything. Because Honey is beginning with a capital it seems it is a class. If the if is always being executed then the passed value must be less than Honey.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your return appears to be wrong (returning the input isn't what you want) - Also, you really should use lower case variable names.

```
public int takeHoney(int h2){
  // Honey changed to honey, use Java naming conventions (please).
  if(h2 <= honey){
    honey = honey - h2;
  } else {
    // Not enough honey... log it? throw an exception? ... return -1...
    System.err.println("Oh bother - Insufficient Honey Encountered");
  }
  return honey;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to return the amount of Honey taken.

Comment: @HotLicks I think he wants to take **ALL OF THE HONEY**. Maybe I am reading to much into `takeHoney(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`.

Comment: You are both right- I want to return the amount of honey taken when this method is run but in my test harness I want to remove all of the honey from the hive at certain points to make sure that certain methods work but I do not wish to return what's left in the hive but what was taken so I can use the method to "feed" my bees later

Comment: @user2973447 You need a method that returns the current amount of honey.  Then pass the result of that into takeHoney.

Comment: @user2973447 Presumably, you should have a single decrement then (assuming each bee will take "1" honey).

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why else statement is executed instead of if statement is because the condition you've specified for if is not met.

```
if(h2 <= Honey) // This does not happen - condition is not met!
```